# How to update database by selecting datagridview row and an update button

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to update database record.
I have two forms, one is main form and other is update form.
now what I want? Main form has `DataGridView` and update `Button`. When I select a `Row` in `DataGridView` and press update `Button`, this content should be loaded to `TextBox`es of the update form.

Note: I can do it by `CellcontentClick` event but I want to do by update `Button`.

```
public void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        update_form fm = new update_form();
        DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        fm.Show();

        fm.id_txt.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        fm.name_txt.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        fm.price_txt.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        fm.discount_txt.Text = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        fm.quantity_txt.Text = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Why are you showing it before setting its values?

Comment: after showing in textboxes i will set new values

Answer (score 0):

simply put the following codes in the Update Button click event:

```
if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
{
    update_form fm = new update_form();
    DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
    fm.Show();

    fm.id_txt.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    fm.name_txt.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    fm.price_txt.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    fm.discount_txt.Text = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
    fm.quantity_txt.Text = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
}
```

regards.